# Dictionary assigning

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
listim=[['1' ,'2'], ['3' , '4'], ['1', '5'], ['4', '1']]
```

I am trying to make dictionary using listim for each number,

I want to have d={'1': 2 , 4, 5 ,'2':1, '3': 4, (...and so on)}

my code is(I can't find the mistake but probably about dictionaries):

```
a=1
dic={}
while a<6:
    for number in listim:
        if number[0]==a:
            if number[1] not in dic[a]:
                dic[a].append(number[1])
        elif number[1]==a:
            if number[0] not in dic[a]:
                dic[a].append(number[0])
        a+=1
```

I couldn't find enough information on web,(I know I can). I hope I was clear enough. Thank you

Comment: This `d={'1': 2 , 4, 5 ,'2':1, '3': 4 ...` makes no sense. Explain better.

Comment: Your example output isn't a valid Python literal, and it isn't clear what you desire.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear because the desired result is not valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `defaultdict` from collections using list as a factory:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

listim=[['1' ,'2'], ['3' , '4'], ['1', '5'], ['4', '1']]

for i in listim:
    d[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))

dict(d)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [2, 5], '3': [4], '4': [1]}
```

Comment: This output doesn't match `d={'1': 2 , 4, 5 ,'2':1, '3': 4, (...and so on)}`

Comment: Agreed, but I assumed OP wanted a list of values for each key and this method provides that.

Comment: I think the OP requests another line in the for loop: `d[i[1]].append(int(i[0]))`

Answer (score -1):

```
dic = {}
for k,v in listim:
    dic[k] = int(v)
```

or even shorter:

```
dic = {k:int(v) for k,v in listim}
```